# How to add an object in list using thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have an object in session for example of a department and this department have children.I got the list of its children, now i want to add this department object in this list.This is very simple at server side but is it possible to do this in thymeleaf.

Comment: Thymeleaf is made for rendering documents. Not for manipulating the model. You should prepare your data first (add the department to the list in your controller/service/etc...) and then render it with Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible to do it in Thymeleaf since it's using [Object-Graph Navigation Language](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/) for evaluating expression values - content of `${...}` block. You can access public methods normally on your model object so calling `boolean List#add(E e)` method works.

But as others mentioned **it's NOT really good idea** and you should redesign your application to fill your model in controller. On the other side if you need to make some nasty hack or just playing around see example below. It's using `th:text` to evaluate adding to list then `th:remove` to clean tag and leave no trace.

*Department Model class:*

```
public class Department {

    private String name;

    public Department(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

*Data in model (eg. session)*

```
List<Department> children = new ArrayList<>();
children.add(new Department("Department 1"));
children.add(new Department("Department 2"));

// In model as *department* variable
Department department = new Department("Main Department");
department.setChildren(children);
```

*Thymeleaf template:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Before</h1>
        <ul>
           <li th:each="child : ${department.children}" th:text="${child.name}"></li>
        </ul>

        <!--/* Here comes a nasty trick! */-->
        <div th:text="${department.children.add(department)}" th:remove="all"></div>

        <h1>Result</h1>
        <ul>
           <li th:each="child : ${department.children}" th:text="${child.name}"></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Before
>
> - Department 1
> - Department 2
>
> Result
>
> - Department 1
> - Department 2
> - Main Department

**P.S.** [Spring Expression Language](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) is used with Spring integration but for this example it makes no difference.

Comment: How could you tie what you did there to a form object so that you can pass it back to the controller

Answer (score -1):

This would be like setting a value in a getXXXX method before returning a value.  It doesn't fit the patter.  Do your data manipulation in the Controller or the Controller to delegate to something else, but not in the view.