# how to properly design "adding object to a list" using springboot with thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

i have two classes Food and FoodType:

```
public class Food {
    //other attributes and constructor and getters and setters are ignored

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = FoodType.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "food_type_",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "fid")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tid")})
    private List<FoodType> types = new ArrayList<>();

}

public class FoodType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String type;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Food.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "types")
    private List<Food> foodList = new ArrayList<>();
    //constructor and getters and setters are ignored
}
```

the requirement is: user should be allowed to add new Food through view, therefore i wonder how to add FoodType to Food in the view?

i've read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448731/how-to-add-an-object-in-list-using-thymeleaf), it seems that it's not a good idea to manipulate data in the view, so if you were the programmer, how would you design the MVC layer so that it can handle the requirement properly?

PS: i know little about JS, is it possible to do it in Thymeleaf?

Comment: Yes, it is possible in thymeleaf. I think your mapping should be `OneToOne` as one food may have one type. If in your case it may have multiple types then `OneToMany`. and you can follow this https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list

Answer (score 0):

You should be following the **MVC layered architecture** to properly achieve what you desire. As a general design guideline:

1. Present a ***UI*** with the form and desired inputs to the user. This is thymeleaf part. (View Layer)
2. Use **Controllers** to capture form post data, validate input and so on.
3. Code a **business layer** to get the Posted data and save objects and so on.
4. Use ***Service and Repository interfaces*** to achieve basic CRUD and similar operations.

As a final remark; what you can do to save multiple `FoodType` to a single `Food` object is as follows (In your controller or business logic layer you can do this):

```
Food aFood = new Food(); // Empty Food to save
aFood.types.add(new FoodType(id, "Pizza"));
aFood.types.add(new FoodType(id, "Burger"));
foodService.save(aFood); // Assuming you are using Service Layer
```

Comment: yes, i do follow the MVC architecture, and what i want is to add FoodType object to a Food object through the view layer. Since the number of the  types of a food can vary, i don't know to achieve this

Comment: You should be doing this with AJAX Post Request and JavaScript. Code a JavaScript to post your FoodType data to a Controller Method.  Please follow this https://grokonez.com/java-integration/integrate-jquery-ajax-post-get-spring-boot-web-service